# svn: E155037: Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted

Tags: svn

I recently did a checkout and the operation stalled so I did a control-c to cancel.  After removing the files from the directory (including the .svn directory), I attempted to do another checkout and received the following error:

```
svn: E155037: Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted
```

Looking at other posts, the most likely solution is to do an SVN cleanup in the current working copy, however, the directory I am trying to checkout into isn't even a working copy.  In fact, if I create a new folder and try to do a checkout from there I get the same message.  If I do an svn cleanup from this directory, I get the expected error message:

```
svn: E155007: 'C:\Users\workspace\project1' is not a working copy directory.
```

Is there a global database that SVN uses I need to flush?   I am using Windows 7 and I have Tortoise SVN installed but I am using the CollabNet Subversion Command-Line Client v1.8.9 (for Windows) for all my operations.  I did however clear all log files associated with Tortoise SVN.

Comment: Parent directories, perhaps?

Comment: No parent directories although I do have some other SVN repos which I can do an svn status on.  I did just for peace of mind, run the cleanup command on those directories and the command executed successfully.  This however did not resolve my issue.  I wonder if there is a lock or log that needs to be flushed on the server?

Answer (score 9):

Actually just found the answer to my question by looking here.

It seems that svn was stuck in the old operation. All of these operations are stored in the database `wc.db` in the `.svn` folder.

By downloading SQLite to my checkout directory and running from cmd:

```
sqlite3.exe .svn/wc.db "select * from work_queue"
```

I got a list of all pending operations. These operations are the ones "not finished". Then by running:

```
sqlite3.exe .svn/wc.db "delete from work_queue"
```

all of these pending operations got deleted and I could commit again.
No need for a re-checkout or anything.

Comment: This worked for me thanks.
It would be great if it was part of the SVN cleanup command.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so when I cancelled the checkout operation after it stalled, for some reason, an .svn directory was placed in my C:\ directory.  Removing the .svn directory from C:\ resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Run Clean Up

For me in versions (my SVN) in Top Nav <<  Action/Clean Up Working Cop Locks.

[image]